# How to resolve : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I'm a beginner in java, I'm coding on Eclipse and I can't run my project because of the error :

"Error: Unable to find or load the main class Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test"

I noticed that there is also a little red cross next to the project name that is not supposed to be there.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZVxS.png)
[littke cross next to the project name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvFcp.png)

Can someone help me with this please ?

I tried to follow advices on forums and videos,like removing and adding again the JRE System library. But it didn't work and I still have the error.

Comment: Look in the Problems view for messages

Comment: Please share your codes in Test.java

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please follow the guidelines. See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).